# Clang doesn't see strdup and some other functions

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm trying to compile a C++ program which for historical reason uses some C library functions on OS X Mavericks. For some reason, Clang doesn't see `strdup`, `popen` and some other functions. I looked inside `string.h`, and it's clear that it wants its C standard bumped up, but I can't do that, because it's C++ code. What do I do?

Here's what I'm using to build the app:

```
#!/bin/sh

PLATFORM=$(uname -s)

SOURCES="..."

if [ "$PLATFORM" = "Linux" ]; then
    PATHS="..."
    LIBS="..."
elif [ "$PLATFORM" = "FreeBSD" ]; then
    PATHS="..."
    LIBS="..."
elif [ "$PLATFORM" = "Darwin" ]; then
    PATHS="..."
    LIBS="..."
else
    echo 'Unknown platform!'
fi

g++ -o app $PATHS -O3 -g3 -Wall -D_POSIX_SOURCE $SOURCES -pthread $LIBS
```

Comment: Neither `strdup` nor `popen` are standard functions. For `strdup`, may I suggest `std::string s2 = s1;`?

Comment: What you could do? you could show us your linkage your compiler flags or your include parts of the source files/header files. Doesn't matter of the solution would this be needed for. On such kind of question, this would never hurt.

Comment: @chris but both Linux and FreeBSD have them, and `strdup` *is* in `string.h`!

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko And you *do* `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes.

Comment: @Zaibis I've edited my question to include my build script.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae I tried that one, but still no.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce, then.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82c9e162a4830b69)

Comment: @chris I find them both in the Posix standard.  They are standard functions, but not standard C (or C++) functions.  OS X is, I believe, Unix, so they should be available, although he may have to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or something similar.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Yes, right. I was just talking about the language standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Posix standard I'm looking at (Posix 2008), the
name of the symbol you want to define is `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.  The
standard says that Posix 1990 specified a macro `_POSIX_SOURCE`,
which has been superseded by `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, so it may just
be an issue of updating your build script.  (I'd go ahead and
define both, and probably also `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, just to be sure.
`_XOPEN_SOURCE` to `700`, and the other two to `200809L`; these
definitions seem to be what Posix 2008 expects.)